# Unit Test Coverage not displaying on Sonarqube - Running through Jenkins Sonar plugin - Test Success displays correctly

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, jenkins, sonarqube

I am currently using jenkins to build a list of different modules for my project. I trigger the builds using Maven. I have sonarqube installed on the server and have set it up correctly so that when a module builds it is displayed on sonarqube and includes all of the basic details such as lines of code, technical debt etc. The modules all have Junit tests that run against them, and sonarqube displays this by saying that the Unit Test Sucess is 100% and it also says the number of tests that have been run in that module. However I cannot get the Unit tests coverage field to display anything and it is blank for all of the modules.

Here is an exert (one module) from my pom.xml

```
customer.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
customer.sonar.sources=D:/TFS/WorkSpace/DEV_2_HYBRID/APP_FO/application/customer/src/main/java
customer.sonar.Hybrid=Customer
customer.sonar.tests=D:/TFS/WorkSpace/DEV_2_HYBRID/APP_FO/application/customer/target/surefire-reports
customer.sonar.junit.reportsPath=D:/TFS/WorkSpace/DEV_2_HYBRID/APP_FO/application/customer/target/surefire-reports
```

The versions of the software I am using are as follows:
Sonarqube v.5.0,
  Jenkins Sonarqube plugin v.2.1,
  Maven v3.2.5

As I said at the beginning the unit test success rate does show successfully, so I believe it is only a small change needed that will get the unit test coverage field working.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Which coverage engine are you using ? How do you generate the coverage report ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the coverage engine of your choice and provide the report to SonarQube via the appropriate property.

If you are using JaCoCo, the report importer is embeded in the java plugin, for other coverage engine (clover, cobertura...) you have to install the dedicated plugin.

For more information see the [dedicated page of documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project).